# Declaring a JDialog that has already been created

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdialog

This question might not make any sense, because I am incredibly confused. I am creating a UI using Swing in Netbeans. I have created a Dialog box by using the Swing UI. I want to open this Dialog when I click on a button on the main Frame. In the Source Code it already declares my Dialog as a variable. When I try to use setVisible on this Dialog variable it on shows the top of the box, the title and an exit button, none of the buttons or text that I added to the Dialog box. I was told I had to declare this Dialog box, but is it not already declared by the automatically generated code?

```
public class ComputeUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ComputeUI
     */
    public ComputeUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        GCDDialog = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        

        GCDDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        GCDDialog.setTitle("GCD");
        GCDDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        GCDDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        GCDDialog.setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        GCDDialog.setName("GCDDialog"); // NOI18N

        jLabel5.setText("Number:");

        jButton3.setText("Compute");

        

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton3))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10)))
                .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10))
                .addContainerGap(71, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout GCDDialogLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(GCDDialog.getContentPane());
        GCDDialog.getContentPane().setLayout(GCDDialogLayout);
        GCDDialogLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            GCDDialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        GCDDialogLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            GCDDialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(GCDDialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        GCDDialog.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("GCDDialog");



        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem2.setText("Exit");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Compute");

        jMenuItem1.setText("GCD");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem1);

        
        

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        GCDDialog.setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ComputeUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ComputeUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ComputeUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ComputeUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ComputeUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    
    private javax.swing.JDialog GCDDialog;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The mostlt NetBeans-generated code here doesn't appear to add any components to `GCDDialog`.  Where did you add these "buttons and text" of which you speak?

Comment: And as for needing declaring the dialog: you're correct, it's already been declared in the NetBeans-generated code; there's no need to declare it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pack()` on the created JDialog GCDDialog before `setVisible(true)`. (side note: variable names should never start with an uppercase letter)

You should use the Netbeans form designer for only one form at a time. So you should have ComputeUI.java and GCDDialog.java. This way Netbeans will correctly initialize both forms.

To make the link between both components, in ComputeUI class:

- declare a global variable: `GCDDialog myDialog;`
- in constructor: `myDialog = new GCDDialog(...);` // if created via Netbeans form designer, pack() will be automatically called
- and in jMenuItem1ActionPerformed: `myDialog.setVisible(true);`